# Making requests @python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.4

I get many errors while trying to execute code:

```
import requests
#import bs4 --not sure if it's necessary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
core = 'http://wwww.lolnexus.com'
name = input('\nName: ')
region =  input('\nRegion NA | EUW | EUNE | BR | TR | RU | LAN | LAS | OCE : ')
full = core + '/' + region + '/' + 'search?name=' + name + '&region=' + region
print (full)
r = requests.get(full)
source = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
print (source)
input()
```

I have no idea what's wrong. It's the beginning of app that I'm trying to write and errors stop me from scraping the rest of the web page.

Errors I get:

```
Name: Fred

Region NA | EUW | EUNE | BR | TR | RU | LAN | LAS | OCE : TR
http://wwww.lolnexus.com/TR/search?name=Fred&region=TR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages
\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 493, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages
\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 291, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1086, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 924, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages
\urllib3\connection.py", line 106, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages
\urllib3\connection.py", line 90, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, *extra_args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 491, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\adapters
.py", line 344, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages
\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 543, in urlopen
    raise MaxRetryError(self, url, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www
w.lolnexus.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /TR/search?name=Fred&r
egion=TR (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\webscraping.py", line 11, in <module>
    r = requests.get(full)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\api.py",
 line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\api.py",
 line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions
.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions
.py", line 567, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.4.egg\requests\adapters
.py", line 392, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='wwww.lolnexus.com'
, port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /TR/search?name=Fred&region=TR (Cause
d by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)
```

What's wrong and is it a good idea to use Requests & BeautifulSoup libraries for web scraping?

Comment: The address lookup failed, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to connect to `http://wwww.lolnexus.com/TR/search?name=Fred&region=TR`, with **four** `w` characters in the domain name. That name does not exist.

Correct the hostname:

```
core = 'http://www.lolnexus.com'
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked such simple mistake :(